# How can I best include over 8000 markers on a google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a wordpress website that is heavily dependent on displaying business locations on a google map as the core of it's design.

The problem is I have over 8000 entries, and this considerably slows down the loading of the home page. I can't use a static map because it disables the geolocation search by distance function (gear icon)

If you'd like to take a look at the site please visit http://findafarmersmarket.org

Please be patient, the site takes about 15 seconds to load.

If you look at the source code you'll see that all 8000 items for the map are included in an inline script. This makes the file about 145,000 lines long and 10 megabytes in size.

How can I better include these items on the map? Is there a best practices for loading large numbers of markers? Defer the script? Load with ajax somehow from an external js file?

Yes, I have read this link https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers.  I'm already using clustering, and in general that's not providing me with enough understandable information on a best direction to move forward. If you've tackled an issue like this before, I'm looking for real world experience in managing 1000s of map markers.

Comment: Have you seen this [article in the documentation ("Too Many Markers!")](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers)?

Comment: Your best option would be to use a tile based rendering like FusionTablesLayer or KmlLayer, and let the tiles be cached by Google's servers.  But that wouldn't support clustering, although you may be able to work out something with KML.  One option that will speed up the loading of your page as is would be to load the marker data via AJAX techniques rather than including all that data in the HTML for the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can try a marker cluster for example:http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps.

Comment: Did you even look at his page?  He is using gmap3 and clustering (of course, it would have been better if he had indicated that in his question)